# bug in listings package?

Tags: errors, listings, package-writing

It seems as if the listings package can not be loaded after all other packages using `\AtBeginDocument`

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook} % 
\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage{listings}}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This raises the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.

<argument> ... \iffalse }{}\lst@ifnumberbychapter
```

In the code sequence

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \@ifundefined{thechapter}{\let\lst@ifnumberbychapter\iffalse}{}
  \lst@ifnumberbychapter
      \newcounter{lstlisting}[chapter]
      \gdef\thelstlisting%
           {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@lstlisting}
  \else
      \newcounter{lstlisting}
      \gdef\thelstlisting{\@arabic\c@lstlisting}
  \fi}
```

Is this a bug or am I misusing `\AtBeginDocument` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably *are* misusing `\AtBeginDocument` :-)

I had no idea packages can be loaded then; but it seems they can be. `listings`, however, uses `\AtBeginDocument` itself. I'd say that's why your code doesn't work.

Actually, I have checked: yes, `listings` `\let`s `\lst@ifnumberbychapter` in `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: I had problems with options clashes which could most easily be resolved by loaded the code of a whole package using `\AtBeginDocument`. since listings does not really depend on other packages and itself has no options clash problem I can load it directly at the loading of my package.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech with `etoolbox` you have `AtEndPreamble`.